# Android editText setError text cut off

Tags: android, android-edittext

The simplest way to explain my issue is with a picture:

[image]

Here is my code for the button

```
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (amountEditText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
                amountEditText.setError("please enter a quantity");
            }

            else{
                //do regular stuff
                dismiss();
            }

        }
    });
```

There is really not much else to post. I have no idea what might cause this. I'm using the standard EditText, nothing custom.

Comment: Could be that issue is in `XML`. Did you hardcoded height of that layout instead for example using `wrap_content`?

Comment: @Yupi I did use wrap content